# Use hdseedid to give all addresses in bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, private-key, public-key

I'm using bitcoin core version 0.18.1 and I'm studying Hd Wallet.
I can see the value hdseedid, and I understand that it's HASH160 of my hd seed.

Can I use this seed to retrieve all my keys?
I tried to put this value in https://iancoleman.io/ like entropia, but I don't find the same address that I can find in dumpwallet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot use that value for that purpose.

Bitcoin Core does not support publicly derivable addresses at all (at this point).